# Google Apps Script (UrlFetchApp REST API) - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: json, rest, dictionary

Trying to fetch data from api url, however getting a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') error.
I do however get data in the logger.

This is my code:

```
function importcogs(aUrl,sheetname) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var aUrl = "https://services.strobbo.com/api/clock/registered?dateFrom=2023-04-12&dateTo=2023-04-13";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(aUrl, {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "apikey": "F932F510-C67A-42AB-83FD-D207ACD36C6F",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "muteHttpExceptions": true,
        "followRedirects": true,
        "validateHttpsCertificates": true,
    }); 
  let obj = JSON.parse(response); //create object

  Logger.log(obj);
  
  let vs = obj.data.map(o => Object.values(o));//data
  vs.unshift(Object.keys(obj.data[0]));//add header
  sh.getRange(1,1,vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);//output to spreadsheet

}
```

Help :-) ?

Comment: It seems to me that you need to do a JSON.parse(response.getContentText()) not just JSON.parse(response)